# MongoDB Shell deleteMany() function is not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have to delete all the data called owner.login.
It means in json data, there are one more Object called owner.

So I tried in MongoSH Beta(MongoDB Compasss) and Mongo Shell with this query but it returns this message and it doesn't removed.

`{ acknowledged: 1, deletedCount: 0 }`

The json data structure looks like this

[image]

So I have to delete all the data that owner.login called 'mojombo'.

So I use this query `db.repos.deleteMany({owner.login:'mojombo'});`

I don't know why the function doesn't work. This command worked well in the Filter function of MongoDB Compass.

Comment: You should post your query so we can see if there any problem with it not matching the document properly, Assuming this isn't the case can you do a sanity check with `findOne` and make sure the document is still there and that you haven't just gotten a none accurate number returned detailing how many documents were deleted?

Comment: `owner.login` should be in quotes. It will delete all **documents** with matching logins.

Comment: And please respect the rules of the site - prefer text over images where possible. It is very possible in your case.

Comment: It would be better if you could you share the complete object(document)..

also as @AlexBlex mentioned, add quotes to `owner.login`